# Apply the same filter in a sequence of images while displaying it animated in the same figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, figure

I'm using MATLAB 2013a.

I have a folder with 1151 images that I want to animate in the same figure (window).

I want to find the *imabsdiff* of each image with only one image (maybe this one as a background image), and I would like it to display it animated and in the same figure, like if it was a video.

I found this code:

```
srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\coil-20-proc\*.jpeg');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\coil-20-proc\',srcFiles(i).name);
    I = imread(filename);
    figure, imshow(I);
end
```

which does read each image from my folder, but it creates a new figure(window) for each image, but I don't want 1151 windows!

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to create a single `imshow` image object and then update the `CData` of this object each time through the loop.

```
directory = 'C:\Users\coil-20-proc';
srcFiles = dir(fullfile(directory, '*.jpeg');
srcFiles = cellfun(@(x)fullfile(directory, x), {srcFiles.name}, 'uni', 0);

hfig = figure();
him = imshow(NaN);

for k = 1:numel(srcFiles)
    im = imread(srcFiles{k});
    %// Perform your operation here

    set(him, 'CData', im);
    axis tight;
    drawnow;
end
```

Comment: And, btw, I'm using MATLAB 2013a.

Comment: There's this error: Error using handle.handle/set
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in VIDEOSEC (line 14)
    set(him, 'CData', im);

Comment: @dawn Are you displaying anything else other than the image?